# Full core of iowait with no actual IO load

Tags: linux, iowait

I'm having an issue with a box that is "randomly" gaining an entire core worth of iowait -- and as far as I can tell there isn't any IO load to go with it, as illustrated by iostat:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.10    0.00   12.61   12.40    0.00   74.90

Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda               0.40         0.00         0.00          0          0
```

I have previously isolated the `%system` load to an issue with `[kipmi0]` as detailed in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas7d580df3d15874988862575fa0050f604 , and that has been happening for much longer than this, so I don't believe it to be related.

The system does have a few automounted NAS filesystems as well, but the NAS in question is not showing a load when this happens.

Is there some way to trace which threads (kernel or userland; either could be causing this) are responsible for the iowait load, and what they are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no full core of `iowait` as no real CPU load is reported. The CPU is just idle and fully available when in this pseudo state.

I wouldn't worry that much about that metric which can be misinterpreted with multi-CPU and multi-threaded hardware.

If you suspect an `i/o` issue, look to `i/o` statistics (eg: `iostat`), not CPU related ones.

Comment: That's problematic.  This is a real issue though -- it has a seriously negative impact on IO throughput when it happens: multiple-second file-writes and so on.

Comment: If you have an I/O issue have a look to the I/O (and network for that matter as you mentioned a NAS) statistics. The CPU has nothing to do with it.